# Why does changing coordinates to characteristics always reduce the PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was looking at the following example of reducing a pde
[image]

In this case we manage to reduce the order of the pde. There are a couple of more examples that employ this technique of finding the characteristics and parameterising through them toreduce the order of the pde.

**My question is**, does this always happen? Is this something like completing the square? I can't seem to prove that there will always be reduction in order. If anybody can help me with that I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: HI, thank you for the reply. Do you know then what is the point of transforming the equation in this format?

Comment: To elaborate on my original question, what guarantees that the only second order term will be cross term?